# Is "in" the correct preposition in "a resesrve in"?

Tags: prepositions

> Besides, Nain Singh and Mani Singh carried quicksilver in an empty coconut shell and a reserve **in** cowrie shells closed with wax. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=DKvtCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=Besides,%20Nain%20Singh%20and%20Mani%20Singh%20carried%20quicksilver%20in%20an%20empty%20coconut%20shell%20and%20a%20reserve%20in%20cowrie%20shells%20closed%20with%20wax&source=bl&ots=zpTULSY1mF&sig=HDP569Bof2zQRz6YlcTaUE4UkeA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiiuqKPjaLdAhVIPN8KHQJcCT8Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=Besides%2C%20Nain%20Singh%20and%20Mani%20Singh%20carried%20quicksilver%20in%20an%20empty%20coconut%20shell%20and%20a%20reserve%20in%20cowrie%20shells%20closed%20with%20wax&f=false))

I thought "reserve" should go with "of". [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reserve) has a number of example sentences with "a reserve *of*", but not a single instance of "a reserve *in*." Google Books also show similar results. Is the usage in the sentence correct?

Comment: The reserve isn't the cowrie shells, it's additional quicksilver **in** the cowrie shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *reserve of X*

You have X and it's a reserve.  There's no information provided on *where* that reserve is.

> *reserve in Y*

You have something and Y is a container holding it.  We don't know what it is though.

> *reserve of X in Y*

This answers both questions.  We know what you have that's a reserve and where it is.

---

So your suspicion that *in* is correct is correct.

Now ... is *of* wrong?

You can say this:

> I have a reserve of water.
>
> I have a reserve of 3 gallons.
>
> I have a reserve of 3 gallons of water.

*Of X* where X is a container quantity works.

It also works when we just want to talk about the type of container without the quantity, as long as context is established.

> I put water in clean milk jugs.  I have a reserve of 20 jugs.

I mean 20 jugs of water.  I would have to say "20 empty jugs" if I meant 20 jugs without water in them after that first sentence.

So *reserve of cowrie shells* would work if what's really meant is *reserve of cowrie shells of quicksliver*.  I'm not sure if cowrie shells is a common "container" of quicksilver, if it is, then this is OK.